# How can I count the total number of occurrences at time step t of an element?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a beginner in R but I would like to write a piece code that requires some R and data science knowledge.

I have a data frame with the following structure; t1 denotes 10 minutes time periods and 1 defines measurements.

```
 t1 t2 t3 t4
  1  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1
  0  1  1  1
  0  1  1  1
  1  0  1  1
```

I would like to identify the duration and starting point for each measurement. For example, there are two 10 min measurements starting at t1 (row 1 and row 5) and there are two 30 minutes measurements that start at t2 (row 3and row 4).

Output:

```
 duration_minutes   t1 t2 t3 t4
      10            2   0  0  0
      20            1   0  1  0
      30            0   2  0  0
      40            1   0  0  0
```

Is there a way to convert the counts into percentages?

```
df<-structure(list(t1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0,1),
                   t2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1,0), t3 = c(0, 1, 1, 1,1), t4 = c(0, 1, 1,  1,1)), row.names = c(NA,5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `rle` which seems like it might be nice fit here. This answer is almost all `base` R, but I couldn't resist dipping into the `tidyverse` for `map_dfr`.

```
library(purrr)

df_rle <- map_dfr(row.names(df), function(x){
  r <- rle(rev(df[x,]))
  rev(r$lengths * r$values * 10)  
})

tab <- table(stack(df_rle), exclude = c('0', NA))
tab
#---------
      ind
values t1 t2 t3
    10  2  0  0
    20  0  0  1
    30  0  2  0
    40  1  0  0
```

If you wanted to represent these as percentages

```
sweep(tab,2, colSums(tab), '/')

#--------
      ind
values        t1        t2        t3
    10 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.0000000
    20 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000
    30 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
    40 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

---

Break it down a bit

The `rle` function when run on a given row gets us pretty close to the desired output. As an example row 5 from `df`.

```
r <- rle(c(1,0,1,1))
r
#-----
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:3] 1 1 2
  values : num [1:3] 1 0 1


# Multiply to get time periods
r$lengths * r$values * 10
# -----
[1] 10  0 20
```

But with a dataframe row as input, values are linked to the last time period not the first. So we reverse the order in which we feed the row to the `rle` function, and then un-reverse (?) the results.

```
r <- rle(df[5,])
r$values
#------
  t1 t2 t4
5  1  0  1

# Reverse before we feed into rle(), reverse the output
r <- rle(rev(df[5,]))
rev(r$lengths * r$values * 10) 
#-----------
  t1 t2 t3
5 10  0 20
```

Then we need to do this reversed rle function on each row. This answer uses `purrr::map_dfr()`, which maps the function to each row, then row binds the results together into a single dataframe.

```
df_rle <- map_dfr(row.names(df), function(x){
  r <- rle(rev(df[x,]))
  rev(r$lengths * r$values * 10)  
}) 


#-----
  t1 t2 t3
1 10  0 NA
2 40 NA NA
3  0 30 NA
4  0 30 NA
5 10  0 20
```

From here, we need to count the values by the 10 minute duration categories. There are several ways to do this. Here is one way in which we first convert `df_rle` to a long form two column dataframe using `stack`, then use the `table` function to tabulate by duration levels.

```
tab <- table(stack(df_rle), exclude = c('0', NA))

#--------
      ind
values t1 t2 t3
    10  2  0  0
    20  0  0  1
    30  0  2  0
    40  1  0  0
```

To convert to percentages (assuming you mean duration as a percent of each time period) you can divide by the original number of measurements, which here is equal to `colSums`. `sweep` can apply the value rowwise (1) or column-wise (2), using the function divide `'/'`.

```
sweep(tab, 2, colSums(tab), '/')
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved it by first pivoting the data into the long format and then counting consecutive 1's to determine the duration of each measurement. Then I count how often each duration occurs per starting time and pivot back to the wider format to get the output that you described (I do not find a column t4 since it doesn't have any new measurements):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(rownr = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'time', values_to = 'value', cols = 1:4) %>% 
  group_by(rownr, grp = cumsum(value == 0)) %>% 
  mutate(duration = 10 * cumsum(value)) %>% 
  filter(duration != 0) %>% 
  summarise(time = first(time), 
            duration = max(duration)) %>% 
  group_by(time, duration) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
  arrange(duration)
```

Comment: you're welcome! Maybe a bit of a long piece of code considering you introduced yourself as a beginner in R, but I couldn't think of a way to simplify it. Anyways, most of it is dplyr package which is very useful for these kinds of things and fairly easy to learn.